# Add a button with a size and add icon inside it in flutter

Tags: flutter, button

I am trying to add an icon to a button.
What steps I followed: Created an icon button filled in the properties.
After this, I wrapped it in a container because I don't want my button to be big.
Here is the image of what I am getting: [![enter image description here][1]][1]

I want that Icon to be fit inside the button,I even tried to wrap the child with centre but still the same results.

My Code Snippet:
Container(
height:18,
width:20,
decoration:BoxDecoration(
border:Border.all(color:Colors.orangeAccent,width:1),
shape:BoxShape.rectangle,
),
child:Centre(child:IconButton(
icon:Icon(Icons.add,
size:16,
color:Colors.orange,),
onPressed:(){},
),),

Comment: Can you share a hand diagram or a picture of what do you want to achieve and also a snippet of the current code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way you can do like below code.

```
Container(
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    child: GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {},
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
          Padding(
            padding:  EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
            child: Text('Add More'),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  )
```

Comment: I need to add box around the Icon.

Comment: Added decoration property and everything just worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code block

```
Container(
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
  child: FlatButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    child: Row(
      children: [
        Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
        Text('Add More')
      ],
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use TextIconButton instead of IconButton.